# Как проверить какой блок на сайте смотрит пользователь

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть сайт, его шапка зафиксирована сверху через position: fixed, и немного заблюрена. Текст у этой шапки белый и нужно сделать так, чтобы текст менялся на черный в зависимости от того, на какой блок смотрит пользователь

Comment: Смотрит глазами?) Или навел мышкой?

Comment: долистал до этого блока, то есть он видит перед собой этот блок

Comment: @ClickName, в каком-то недалеком веб-будущем: "mozilla анонсирует Visual Perception API, и планы скорой стандартизации Mind Control API")))

Comment: @tnixxx, советую посмотреть [вопросы об использовании `IntersectionObserver`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+IntersectionObserver) - более современном способе определения "доскролла до элемента" (по сравнению с древним способом прослушивания события `scroll`).

Answer (score 2):

Весьма неплохая библиотека для этого - [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver).
Псевдоэлемента или чего-либо подобного для отслеживания блока на экране нет, поэтому без JS не обойтись. Вот рабочий [пример](https://codepen.io/Seasle/pen/QWyYRQL):

```js
const debug = document.querySelector('.debug');
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

const displayed = {};

function scrollTracking(entries) {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    displayed[entry.target.id] = entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.2;
  }

  debug.textContent = Object
    .entries(displayed)
    .filter(([id, inViewport]) => inViewport)
    .map(([id, inViewport]) => id)
    .join('\n');
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(scrollTracking, {
  threshold: [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
});

boxes.forEach(element => observer.observe(element));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.debug {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.box {
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 50px;
  font: 200px 'Segoe UI', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #dddddd;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<pre class="debug"></pre>
<div class="box" id="box_1">1</div>
<div class="box" id="box_2">2</div>
<div class="box" id="box_3">3</div>
<div class="box" id="box_4">4</div>
<div class="box" id="box_5">5</div>
<div class="box" id="box_6">6</div>
<div class="box" id="box_7">7</div>
<div class="box" id="box_8">8</div>
<div class="box" id="box_9">9</div>
<div class="box" id="box_10">10</div>
```